# Where can I find an older version of the macromedia flash plugin?

Tags: flash-player

I'm currently using Macromedia Flash 10.2.152.32 but I'm having problem with a specific site that uses a brightcove.com live streaming.
Reading on google groups I found out that there is a problem with 10.2.* version so I would like to go back to 10.1.* but I can't find it on the official adobe page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the official Adobe download, you can check out the [Archived Adobe Flash Plugin](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14266.html) page. The files here, though, look they they are actually meant for developers (and the installer is huge - 10.1 is 81 MB).

Instead, you might want to look at FileHippo. They usually have older version of files and installers, and for both the [IE flash plugin](http://filehippo.com/download_flashplayer_ie/) and [Non-IE flash plugin](http://filehippo.com/download_flashplayer_firefox/8674/),  they have slightly over a year's worth of installers.

I would grab the most recent version of 10.1, which is 10.1.102.64. [IE version](http://filehippo.com/download_flashplayer_ie/8673/) | [Non-IE version](http://filehippo.com/download_flashplayer_firefox/8674/)

Comment: One can only love the clever "products affected" information on that page.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend not making a habit of having an out of date version of Flash, but adobe keeps these available here: [Flashplayer Archive for Developers](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14266.html)

Comment: thanks, but those files are pretty big to be the binary version of the plugin.